# How to copy text from one textbox to another after you push a button in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input

So here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button>Go</button><br>
<input type="text" id="output">
```

So what I want to do is when you type something into the first box and press go it prints it to the second box.  If anyone could help me then thank you.

Comment: what did you try? Any error? Take a look at w3schools.com it is in the basics of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="copyText()">Go</button><br>
<input type="text" id="output">
```

**JS**

```
function copyText(){
   document.getElementById("output").value=document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was talking to a friend of mine but they just told me LEARN IT.  Granted I am a complete noob in javascript but... THANKS

Answer (score 1):

If you add an id to the button, you could do this:

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("output").value = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rco9jvgg/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick='change()'>Go</button><br>
<input type="text" id="output">
    <script>
        function change(){
            var inputValue=document.getElementById('input').value;
            var output = document.getElementById('output');
            output.value=inputValue;
        }


    </script>
```

You need to add the onclick event and define a function, in this case I define the change() function.
Inside the function you get the text in the textfield with the id input and then you have to set that value to the other textfield (output) with output.value=inputvalue

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/e49wqear/.

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        $("#output").val($("#input").val());    
    });
});
```